# Error in mounted hook: "TypeError: edge is undefined" when using dagre-d3 with vue2

Tags: d3.js, vuejs2, vue-component, dagre-d3

I'm trying to set up very simple example with `Vue2` using `dagre-d3` for rendering directed graphs.
Unfortunately, even with extremely simple example, it wont work. Examples found elsewhere online are using older version of `d3`.
Currently, `Vue2` app is mostly default template with a router with a `typescript` as language. `Diagram` component is in `javascript` (due to missing types in my code for `d3` and `dagre-d3`).

When running the component mentioned below, following error happens and nothing is shown in the `<svg>` block.

```
Error in mounted hook: "TypeError: edge is undefined"
```

And it happens on this line

```
render(container, g);
```

Only thing i can think off is that i might be missing some some dependencies or that all components must be typescript.

Help?

Diagram.vue:

```
<template>
  <div class="myback">
    <h1>This is a diagram component</h1>
    <svg>
      <g></g>
    </svg>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import * as d3 from "d3";
import dagreD3 from "dagre-d3";

// let edges = {}
// let nodes = {}
// let g = new dagreD3.graphlib.Graph().setGraph({})

export default {
  /*
    data () {
        return {
            edges: {},
            nodes: {}
        }
    },
    */

  mounted() {
    /* create graph itself */
    const g = new dagreD3.graphlib.Graph().setGraph({});
    g.setGraph({
      nodesep: 70,
      ranksep: 50,
      rankdir: "LR",
      marginx: 20,
      marginy: 20,
    });
    console.log(g);

    const render = new dagreD3.render(); // eslint-disable-line new-cap
    console.log(render);

    const svg = d3.select("svg");
    const container = svg.select("g");

    console.log(svg);
    console.log(container);

    /* define zoom behavior */
    function zoomed(e) {
      container.attr("transform", e.transform);
    }

    const zoom = d3.zoom().scaleExtent([1, 10]).on("zoom", zoomed);

    g.setNode("kspacey", { label: "Kevin Spacey", width: 144, height: 100 });
    g.setNode("blabla", { label: "blabla", width: 144, height: 100 });

    g.setEdge("kspacey", "blabla");

    svg.call(zoom);

    render(container, g);
  },
  /*
    methods: {
        draw () {
        }
    }
    */
};
</script>

<style scoped>
section {
  margin-bottom: 3em;
}

section p {
  text-align: justify;
}

svg {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: white;
  width: 800px;
  height: 600px;
}

text {
  font-weight: 300;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serf;
  font-size: 14px;
}

path.link {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #666;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.node rect {
  stroke: #333;
  fill: #fff;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.myback {
  background: gray;
}
</style>
```

Codesanbox link is [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/reverent-swartz-twtp6?file=/src/components/Diagram.vue)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were two problems with this component:

1. Default edge label needs to be set

I was missing a call on the graph instantiation. It should have been

```
const g = new dagreD3.graphlib.Graph()
    .setGraph({})
    .setDefaultEdgeLabel(function () { return {} })
```

2. d3.select() was selecting and using wrong node for rendering. Due to usage of fontawesome, in the router-link, i was using following

> ```
> <router-link to="/about">
>     <font-awesome-icon :icon="['fas', 'info-circle']" />
> </router-link>
> ```

Because the font-awesome-icon is rendered to `<svg>` element, rendering was happening in that node, but i only noticed this after fix with the default edge.

If someone has the same issue, [this](https://dagrejs.github.io/project/dagre-d3/latest/demo/clusters.html) example was the one that helped me identify explained issues